# What's the difference between response.body() and object returned by the callback?

Tags: spark-java

From Spark Java [documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#response):

```
response.body("Hello");        // sets content to Hello
```

And from [Route's JavaDoc](http://javadox.com/com.sparkjava/spark-core/2.3/spark/Route.html#handle-spark.Request-spark.Response-):

```
@return The content to be set in the response
```

So what's the difference? Could someone explain to me pls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An actual difference however is that `response.body()` accepts only `String`, while in the callback you can `return` any object that can be serialized to `String` and most importantly streams.

`response.body()` should be mostly used in exception handlers and after filters, and the callback `return` in normal routes.

Answer (score 1):

As you've pointed out, they both can be used to set the response body.  I think the @return is part of a typical http endpoint.

response.body() is useful for exception handling.

```
exception(NotFoundException.class, (e, request, response) -> {
    response.status(404);
    response.body("Resource not found");
});
```

Sparkjava is a bare bones framework and it's meant to be built on top of.  response.body() makes sparkjava easily extensible in contexts where you don't have access to the "return" object.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no difference on what it does, but they both exist so it's easy to set the response body in different contexts. For example you could use `response.body` in an exception handler or even filter, but as you may notice, the `return` way is "nicer" in a route declaration.